# Best practice for MEAN stack project

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I'm working on a MEAN stack project.
It has front-end for the web and app for mobile also has an admin panel.

What is the best scenario?

- One Restful API using Nodejs for app and web and the admin panel will be
  embedded not using API but using ejs and NodeJS?
- One Restful API for all and also admin panel will use API and it
  will be a separate project?

Comment: If you mentioned MEAN stack project then I think it will use MongoDB, Express, AngularJS and Node.js. For me I will create two projects:

- The first project for server-side ( back-end ) using Node.js, Express and MongoDB

- The second project is written by AngularJS for client-side

Comment: there is two client sides, one for users and one for admins, should i separate them ?

Comment: No, you don't need to separate them. Just combine both of them in one client side and use code to distinguish them.

Comment: I can think of no reason to separate the admin panel into a separate server process. That's just more complication with no practical deployment benefit I can think of.

Comment: good point, the reason behind my thoughts is its a single web page app so the code will contain the whole admin panel components and i will not use in the web and the vise versa